# Which battery grip should I get for my Canon 60D and why?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, canon, canon-60d, battery-grip

I'd like to buy a Canon 60D battery grip not only for the extra battery power but also, and mainly because of the added size and the extra buttons. (I have huge hands)

My question is; How is [this $380 grip from our local Canon distributor](http://www.futureshop.ca/en-CA/product/canon-canon-battery-grip-for-eos-60d-bg-e9-web-only-web-only-bg-e9/10154970.aspx?path=e35732482eb432cfb820630908b0408ben02) different from [this $50 grip available on amazon](http://www.amazon.ca/Professional-Battery-60D-Digital-Camera/dp/B004IY6Z58).  ($320 less)

Is there any reason why I should buy one over the other?  Any positive/negative experiences with either unit?

Comment: I would suggest adding info about your planned use, such as professional/amateur, how often you shoot in foul weather, etc.

Comment: AFAIK - The off brand are great for everyone except the most serious photographers who need it to work day in, day out. For the rest of us, they are quite close reproductions of the real thing, and you do save a good amount.

Comment: See this http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1243/recommendations-for-off-brand-battery-grips-for-dslrs

Comment: Okay, Canon seems to be taking the mickey with that grip (the comparable Nikons are cheaper, and Nikon isn't known for bargain accessories either). But somewhat tangential to your question: if you're looking at anything more than a point-and-shoot in Canada, look at either Vistek ( http://vistek.ca ) or Henry's (http://www.henrys.com ). Future Shop/Best Buy are hugely overpriced when it comes to DSLRs and accessories. That said, Canon accessories are expensive in Canada; you can get the BG-E9 for $170 through either Adorama or B&H (with GST owing; there should be no duty).

Comment: thanks for your comments! Very helpful. @Stan - I used those links as extreme examples. I did get a lens from Vistek in the past and was happy with the service but they still seem to have overpriced this item @ $330.  I usually order from B&H but then it's a bit of a drive to the border to pick it up, the hassle, etc.  I guess my question really is; is the off-brand grip a quality enough item to use every day.

Comment: @MikeW - thanks for the link. I wouldn't have posted my question if I came across it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I own two Canon EOS bodies, a 450D and a 7D. I did quite a bit of research on battery grips for the 450D some time ago, and settles on a Zeikos brand one. I was extremely happy with it. The build quality was superb, the grip rubber was nice and grippy, and very similar to the native grip of the camera body, and it offered all of the features of a Canon brand grip.

I purchased another Zeikos grip for my 7D at the same time I purchased the body. I'm just as happy with the 7D version of the Zeikos grip as I was with the 450D version. I think it may lack one or two of the features of the Canon brand grip, but I don't think they were particularly important to me when I made the decision. All the critical functionality is there, and most importantly, the grip supports two batteries rather than one. Additionally, Zeikos grips always support regular old Duracell, Energizer, Rayovac batteries...AA type for the 450D, 9v for the 7D...and in a pinch, that can be EXTREMEY valuable.

And on top of it all, the Zeikos grips are a small fraction the cost of a Canon brand grip. I would recommend them to anyone who needs a grip and doesn't insist on brand matching. The Zeikos grip for the 60D lists for $90, while the Canon grip for the 60D lists for $270. On Amazon, the [Zeikos](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004LBDA60) is currently $61.66, and the [Canon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00449NU3W) is currently $174.88, a difference of almost three times. Functionally, I don't think there is a scrap of functional difference between the two, and the Zeikos is a few ounces lighter.

Answer (score 0):

I have a "Meike" grip for my 6d. It's great! Works fine.
However, I would NOT trust it on a rainy day where the camera is bound to get wet.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have got myself a "Meike" LCD grip for my 550d. The grip is working perfect and i do not want to miss it ever. The LCD timer functions are usable but one needs a little while to get thru the chinenglish manual. Having said this the camera takes at times pictures without either shutterbutton being pressed. In the film days it would bother me but no i see it as a reminder to switch the camera off.