# What options to have better grip of my camera?

Tags: accessories, handling

Big hands and a small camera is sometimes no problem at all, one might even be happy with a small camera. At other times a small camera can be hard to operate if you can't get good hold - even when the camera has a grip shaped body. Most DSLR cameras and many compact cameras have such a grip, but what if even that is not enough?

I know the most common solution is to buy a battery grip, and one might want it just to get a better hold of the camera. Another question deals with that idea (though the title only mentions Canon 600D). [Is it worth buying a battery grip even if I don't care about the battery capacity?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/22483/17441)

What if there is no battery grip available for my camera? What other options is there to make a camera better to hold and handle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try a [hand strap](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/search?atclk=Strap+Style_Hand+Grip+Strap&ci=283&N=4075788787+4246734081). These vary in price from $10 to $100, and similarly in construction and comfort, but the concept is the same: attaches to your camera (either by the normal strap lugs, via the tripod screw, or occasionally in some specialized way), and then you wrap your hand securely through.

It's not just like those little wrist straps that come with a point and shoot, which are there to keep you from dropping the thing in a tourist fountain; here, you actually grip the camera securely to your hand.

Comment: Definitely worth a try, though I suspect it would work better for a camera with a larger body. My palm is 11 cm wide. I'll go to a camera store and see how such strap fits.

Answer (score 2):

i have heard of people putting bike handlebar grip tape on their camera...
[have a look at this stuff.](http://www.rawk.com/p1643/jessup-black-grip-tape/?gclid=CIurguzmzrYCFXHLtAodLmEAaw)

Comment: Good idea, and a fine example of outside-the-box thinking. You could also do well to expand your answer with some thought given to what downsides there might be with using griptape, and if tape has other benefits besides improved grip.

Answer (score 1):

Try a pair of shooting gloves that have the right thumb and index finger removed like [these](http://abbyshot.com/gaming/dante-shooting-gloves/) or [these](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008A6MRJI). You can also use a more typical 3/4 or 1/2 finger design like [these](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004RU9RT4) marketed as biker's gloves. These styles come in a wide variety of materials. [These](http://www.wayfair.com/Neosport-3-4-Finger-Glove-SG15V-QOA1026.html)  are made of spandex and synthetic leather for use when wearing a wetsuit.

Comment: Interesting. I'd rather have the improvement in the camera than to have more items hanging around, but if all of the other ideas fail, this could save it. Never used such special sports gloves, so it could be better idea than I can imagine atm.

Answer (score 1):

I have actually been surprised just how much usage my battery grip gets.  I got it specifically for battery life alone, but even without that, the vertical grip capability it has for taking shots rotated 90 degrees is fantastic.  I wouldn't have paid what I paid for it if I didn't get the battery capacity, but having it, I do use it just for day to day handling improvements.

There are also many rigging systems you can get for camera's that will give better grips including systems that will let you shoulder mount a DSLR or even a point and shoot, though these systems tend to be more expensive than battery grips when professionally produced.  If you are decent with metal working, you can probably make one yourself pretty cheap just using aluminum pipes and a tripod mount though.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I can't work aluminum, but I consider myself pretty agile with welding and such simple jobs with iron. Going to think about a diy grip.

Answer (score 0):

Buy a third party battery grip. They're cheap and mine worked. $50 for a 6d battery grip. Win! Thank you Meike (the brand of my battery grip)

Comment: Thanks. There is other questions dealing with battery grips, like [Why buy a battery grip](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/24073/why-buy-a-battery-grip) and this question tries to cover what other options there is to battery grips.

Comment: Yeah sorry.  I personally bought my battery grip primarily for the vertical shooting feature rather than the extra battery slot. Too much vertical shooting w/o battery grip makes my shoulder hurt.